# Issue in Parameterizing Config Block From a Macro using Jinja

Tags: google-bigquery, model, configuration, jinja2, dbt

I wanted to parameterize the Config Block example namely jobid here in this context, for a DBT model  through a Macro.
My macro returns the jobid, and it available to use in the model. But while that is assigned to the model config block, jobid assignment is not happening and model is getting failed finally.

In the DBT model,  generally config block, will be like this:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        job_id = 0001
    )
}}
```

I wanted to remove this hardcoding of jobid inside macro, I tried two ways:

Type 1:Hardcoding it outside and substituting it back, it works fine.

```
{% set job_id = 0001 %} -- Hardcoding it outside

{{ print("job_id  is" ~ job_id) }}

{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        job_id = job_id -- Assigned the jobid through the local variable
    )
}}

{{ print("job_id  is" ~ job_id) }}
```

Type 2: My Ultimate aim is to parameterize it via a macro as below which returns the jobid for me.

```
{% set v_job_id = [ configmacro() ] %}  -- Getting Jobid by calling a macro

{% set job_id = v_job_id[0] %} 

{{ print("job_id  is" ~ job_id) }}

{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        job_id = job_id -- Assigned the jobid through the local variable
    )
}}

{{ print("job_id  is" ~ job_id) }}
```

But in this case, job_id is available for use and even getting printed before and after config block through the print statements. But inside config block, job_id substitution not happening and the model is failing.

I feel the Jinja template have some parsing issue or something.

Comment: I am thinking Model config will be loaded at parsing phase of a model execution while the macro configmacro will not be executed in parsing phase, hence my job id will be empty and it cannot be updated the configuration during execution phase. I think thats the reason for this issue. So, my understanding is, we cannot update the model config in execution phase. I have changed my approach slightly different by passing model name as the input to downstream materialization macro code, I will fetch the jobid directly there itself and use it. Please let me know if there are any other way to handle.